# Get the value of selected time and day using a DatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the value of the selected time and date when the Datepicker is shown.
I achieved the UI and shown the date and time picker when onTap.
The problem is that I can get the value after selected. The idea would be to render it somewhere in the screen as follows:

time selected: .....
date selected: .....

This is my code regarding the popUp of the DayPicker and the function that gets the value:

function and variables:

```
  DateTime? _dateTime;
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay(hour: 7, minute: 15);

  void _selectTime() async {
    final newTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _time,
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
    );
    if (newTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        _time = newTime;
      });
    }
  }
```

Gesture Detector to show the PickerDate:

```
GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          showDatePicker(
                            context: context,
                            initialDate: _dateTime ?? DateTime.now(),
                            firstDate: DateTime(2021),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2023),
                            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                              return Theme(
                                data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                                  primaryColor: context.themeSettings.lightRed,
                                  accentColor: context.themeSettings.lightRed,
                                  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: context.themeSettings.lightRed),
                                  buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
                                ),
                                child: child!,
                              );
                            },
                          ).then(
                            (date) {
                              setState(
                                () {
                                  _dateTime = date;
                                },
                              );
                              print('date');
                            },
                          );
                        },
```

Gesture detector to show the DatePicker:

```
GestureDetector(
                        onTap: _selectTime,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: context.themeSettings.mediumGray),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                              5.0,
                            ) //
                                ),
                          ),
                          width: width * 0.40,
                          height: height * 0.05,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Pick a time',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: context.themeSettings.darkText, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

The only thing missing is to show the actual value selected for both information.
what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It remains only to display the time for the user. With `Text()`.
Your time value in the `_time` variable
and dates in `_dateTime`

```
Text("time selected: $_time date selected: _dateTime",),
```

put this somewhere in your interface

for example in a `child` in `GestureDetector`

**upd (24.08.2021):**

I can not understand what your problem may be, according to the code fragments that you showed
Try to use code close to this
[Source of code](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-datepicker-in-flutter-37e84f7d8d6c)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: DatePickerDemo(),
    );
  }
}


class DatePickerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DatePickerDemoState createState() => _DatePickerDemoState();
}

class _DatePickerDemoState extends State<DatePickerDemo> {
  /// Which holds the selected date
  /// Defaults to today's date.
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 55, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
              child: Text(
                'Select date',
                style:
                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I added it but its not showing anything

Comment: @dosytres, are you using StatefulWidget or StatelessWidget ?

Comment: @dosytres, i updated the answer let me know about the results